# summation of pandas timestamp and array containing timedelta values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, time-series

I've a start date and an array containing irregular sample values in days that I would like to use as date index for pandas series.

Like:

```
In [233]: date = pd.Timestamp('2015-10-17 08:00:00')
Out[233]: Timestamp('2015-10-17 08:00:00')

In [234]: sample_size = np.array([0,10,13,19,30])
Out[234]: array([  0.,  16.,  32.,  48.,  64.])
```

Now I could make use of a list and the following for loop to create the pandas datetime series:

```
In [235]: all_dates = []
          for stepsize in sample_size:
              days = pd.Timedelta(stepsize, 'D')
              all_dates.append(date + days)
          pd.Series(all_dates)
Out[235]: 2015-10-17 08:00:00
          2015-10-27 08:00:00
          2015-10-30 08:00:00
          2015-11-05 08:00:00
          2015-11-16 08:00:00
          dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But I was hoping for a purely numpy or pandas solution without the need of a list and for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [11]:
pd.Series(pd.TimedeltaIndex(sample_size , unit = 'D') + date)
Out[11]:
0   2015-10-17 08:00:00
1   2015-10-27 08:00:00
2   2015-10-30 08:00:00
3   2015-11-05 08:00:00
4   2015-11-16 08:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

first you need to create a time delta of all values you want to add to your date , notice I've assigned `D` as a parameter which means we need the time delta frequency to be in days , because we want to add days to our date

```
In [42]:
time_delta = pd.TimedeltaIndex(sample_size, unit = 'D')
time_delta
Out[42]:
TimedeltaIndex(['0 days', '10 days', '13 days', '19 days', '30 days'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

then in order to add your time delta to your date , you need to fulfill two conditions , first you need to create a `timeseries` of your date so that later you can add time delta to it , the second thing is that newly created `timeseries` must have the same number of elements of your `timedelta` , and this can be achieved by `repeat(len(sample_size)`

```
In [40]:
time_stamp = pd.Series(np.array(date).repeat(len(sample_size)))
time_stamp
Out[40]:
0   2015-10-17 08:00:00
1   2015-10-17 08:00:00
2   2015-10-17 08:00:00
3   2015-10-17 08:00:00
4   2015-10-17 08:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [41]:
time_stamp + time_delta
Out[41]:
0   2015-10-17 08:00:00
1   2015-10-27 08:00:00
2   2015-10-30 08:00:00
3   2015-11-05 08:00:00
4   2015-11-16 08:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: that seems to work, so first have to create a series equal to `date` and with the length of `sample_size`. Still little cumbersome though

Comment: I've added some explanations to elaborate more on how this solution works

Comment: you don't need to manually broadcast, simply add them and it will work ``Series(pd.to_timedelta(sample_size,unit='D') + date)``